# Utilizando ng-Options como faço filter que interprete exatamente o valor informado

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Irei por um exemplo apenas para teste:

Nesse exemplo quando coloco `filter:chart.id='1'`, além de ele me retornar o id 1 ele me retorna o id 10, como eu faria para que retornasse apenas o id=1?

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    
  $scope.chartList = [ 
    { "id" : 1, "name" : "chart 1", "order" : 1, "active" : false },
    { "id" : 2, "name" : "chart 2", "order" : 2, "active" : false },
    { "id" : 3, "name" : "chart 3", "order" : 3, "active" : true },
    { "id" : 4, "name" : "chart 4", "order" : 4, "active" : true }, 
    { "id" : 10, "name" : "chart 10", "order" : 5, "active" : true }
  ];
}
```

```css
.done-true {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <select ng-model="toAddChart" ng-options="chart.id as chart.name for chart in chartList | filter:chart.id='1'">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por isso eu gosto do [ReactJs](https://facebook.github.io/react/)...

Answer (score 3):

Dependendo da versão do AngularJS que estiver usando você pode forçar ele a fazer uma comparação exata passando `true` como parâmetro para o filter

```
ng-options="chart.id as chart.name for chart in chartList | filter:chart.id=1:true"
```

Mas deve levar em consideração que a comparação desta forma é exata, então no seu exemplo existiam aspas simples no `filter:chart.id='1'`, repare que eu removi elas no meu exemplo, com elas ele não funcionaria pois ele compararia um texto com um número e o resultado seria falso.

Em versões antigas do AngularJS você pode criar uma função para fazer este filtro

```
$scope.meuFiltro = function(valor){
    return function(obj){
        return obj.id == valor;
    }
};
```

Então usaria ela passando o valor que quer filtrar

```
ng-options="chart.id as chart.name for chart in chartList | filter:meuFiltro(1)"
```

Comment: Funcionou! Só por duvida a partir de qual versão o parâmetro true funciona?

Comment: Pela documentação me parece ser a partir da versão 1.1.3